# Clicking "Check All" button in a JS dialog window results in all checkboxes in the main page being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, events, frontend

Clicking a button on the main page to add a sku opens up a new window with a search field as seen in the image below. This pop-up has got a Check All button which when clicked selects all checkboxes both on the pop-up window and the main page. I don't know why it selects those on the main instead of just selecting the ones in the pop-up window.

[image]

Below is the code to select the checkboxes.

```
    self.element.dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 838,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        title: "Add skus",
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Add Skus': function() {
                self._save();
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Check all' : function(){
                $(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you share your relevant html, JavaScript and css so we can reproduce your problem in order to help?

Comment: is this live somewhere ? Also , you can use outer div where all your checkbox are present as a selector.

Comment: @Swati, yes. But you need access to view this page. The answer actually works, but there is a minor problem with it. I explained in the comment to burakk below.

Comment: @Swati, I think it possible to give you the access to the dev server if you like.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica, please have a look at the JS code here at https://codepen.io/nbkqmkne-the-encoder/pen/ExmBXOq

Comment: @CodeForGood let me know .

Comment: @Swati, Thanks a lot. Could you please share your skype so I can share the credentials over it? Sharing credentials here even for dev is not right decision.

Comment: @Swati, you can find me by pramodraam@gmail.com on skype.

Comment: @Swati, Hi Swati, I hope you are keeping well. I never forget the help you did last year.  I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this statement:

```
$(':checkbox', this).attr('checked', true);
```

This adds context (the dialog box in this case) to the selector.

Comment: This works except that it is now only the first of the checkboxes on the main page that gets checked along with all those in the pop-up window as I wanted it to happen. This happens when the main page loads. Please look into how to ensure none of the checkboxes on the main page gets checked.

Comment: This is the output I see on the main page: `<button type="button" id="new_simpleOption" data-icon="plusthick" class="smallButton ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false" title="Add Option"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-plusthick"></span><span class="ui-button-text">Add Option</span></button>`

Comment: Try replacing this with self. 
$(':checkbox', self).attr('checked', true);

Comment: If it doesn't work, add console.log(self); and console.log(self.element); statements before the self.element.dialog call.

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, but what was working with the last code isn't working any more.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Please have a look at the full code at  codepen.io/nbkqmkne-the-encoder/pen/ExmBXOq I am aware your time is as valuable as anybody else's. Your helping others means a lot to people like me as I am just beginning to learn JS.

Comment: It's OK. The code at CodePen doesn't work. I don't see any HTML or CSS.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. This JS file is part of our backend order management system. I am at the moment not sure where the HTML and CSS for this is.  Let me find them out and get back to you.

Comment: I've a request for you. Could you please have a look at this post to see if you can suggest some solutions? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71910147/close-previously-opened-accordion-with-pure-javascript?noredirect=1#comment127070019_71910147